# Как вывести последний элемент строки в f#

Tags: .net, f#

То есть у меня есть список чисел float,я перевожу их в string и хочу извлечь последний элемент,как это сделать?

Comment: Последний символ строки нужен? Не уверен, что будет работать, но по идее к последнему элементу массива (строка это массив символов) можно обратиться через `^`, т.е будет `mystring[^1]`, это вытащит первый элемент с конца

Comment: Если ещё актуально, то, например, так: "12345" |> Seq.last